# formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. How to fix this error?

Tags: html, angular, forms

My HTML source code as follows,

```
    <p>
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onFormSubmit()">
          <mat-label>Add a List</mat-label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="listName" matInput placeholder="Placeholder" formControlName="name" #nameInput fxFlex>
         <mat-icon matSuffix class="check" (click)="onFormSubmit()">check</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon matSuffix class="clear" (click)="closeForm()">clear</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
   </p>
```

when running this code following error shows on the console,

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
```

how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Typo ? You wrote:

```
[formGroup]="form"
```

It should be:

```
[formGroup]="myGroup"
```

Comment: is `myGroup`, the name of the form, BTW, I'm not prety sure use the directive [formGroup] in mat-form-field, I don't know if it's better use the directive in the `<p>`

Comment: @TharinduLakshan it should myGroup, i just made a typo too...

Comment: on .ts file this variables are declared `public listName:string;  formActive: boolean;  form: FormGroup;`